# Vue js, how do I dynamically update content based on the url parameters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, router

I'm trying to dynamically update the content using url parameters. So I'm basically reusing the view to render content based on the url.
while that works fine for the initial load, it won't update when I'm trying to access a different link using the same view.
I've to reload the page in order for the content to update based on the new url params.
I read things and examples about using a watcher to achieve what I need, however all the examples used custom methods which I'm not interested in,
so I'm not sure how to restracture my code to work with watchers

My script looks as follows

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
 items: [],
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost/test/records/"+this.$route.params.dates+"/"+this.$route.params.datee);
    this.items = response.data.data;
  },
};
</script>
```

the params this.$route.params.dates and this.$route.params.datee are dates that allow me to fetch data between these two values.

Comment: Using a watcher on `$route` is exactly how to solve the problem, why don't you want to do that?